# How to get first key from object using docker inspect --format (get name of network of container)

Tags: docker

I have command like this:

```
$ docker inspect reacthublh_mysql_1 -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
```

which extract for me output:

```
{"reacthublh-network":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":["1b905711e127","mysql"],"NetworkID":"d2b6bd4815a2eb48a57d05e5d219894f453c15e3f8b5a331a5f0668ed98f4730","EndpointID":"c71240571cc1cfb7bd50119aaf6aaef3dfbc2dc56732e0fd6f593ebe00861edc","Gateway":"172.30.0.1","IPAddress":"172.30.0.2","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:1e:00:02","DriverOpts":null}}
```

the question is how to extract only **reacthublh-network** which is first key of json object?

UPDATE:

The only way that I found now is:

```
$ docker inspect reacthublh_mysql_1 -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}" | cut -d '"' -f2
```

which outputs exactly what I need but I'm curious if it's still possible to do it in --format parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `docker inspect -f` option uses the Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) language, with fairly few extensions.  I don't think it's directly possible to print only the first network name, but it is possible to print out all of the network names and no other details.  The trick here is to iterate over that `Networks` object as a map and print out the keys:

```sh
docker inspect jolly_hodgkin \
  -f '{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{printf "%s\n" $k}}{{end}}'
```

If you have a purpose-built command-line tool for JSON manipulation (like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) its query language might be more powerful and more suited for the data manipulation you need.  A `jq` invocation to specifically get the name of the first Docker network might look like

```sh
docker inspect jolly_hodgkin \
  | jq -r '.[].NetworkSettings.Networks | keys | first'
```