# docker inspect, return field key as string

Tags: docker

I am trying to get the network name of containers. I tried:

```
docker inspect db_dev -f "{{index  .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
```

returns:

```
map[mynet_default:0xc0005dc000]
```

How do I return the string "mynet_default" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59551883/9434800):

```
docker inspect db_dev \
  -f '{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{print $k}}{{end}}'
```

You might want to use `printf "%s\n" $k` if there are multiple networks otherwise they will be concatenated without separator.

---

From the [`range` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables):

> If a `range` action initializes a variable, the variable is set to the successive elements of the iteration. Also, a `range` may declare two variables, separated by a comma.